# Xml to map conversion in mule esb

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-studio, dataweave

I have a following xml:

```
<Root><Record><Element   name=""></Element> <Element    name=""></Element></Record>< <Record></Record>.......</Root>
```

The whole xml follows the above pattern. This must be given as input to batch step for record by record processing...

```
  Each record in the batch step=<Record> element.(see the sample example)
```

I know i need to xml to map conversion for giving to batchstep as input. I have implemented this using dataweave...but i believe it has low performance..

Is there any transformer that directly transforms xml to equivalent map.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide the statistics or some data points to show how slow it is ? Also can you provide the DataWeave code that you use for this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You will be suprised by the performance of DataWeave, it's very fast and very powerful!
Use it, it's best practice to do so for your usecase.
Why low performance, what is your amount of data and what are your timings?
I am processing 30k rows in less than 5 seconds.